# UDF for a combination of Excel Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

I have 2 combinations of formulas for which i would like to create some UDFs.

1. `=Sum(Len(where) - Len(Substitute(where, what, ""))) / Len(what)`
   where = range in which the function to look
   what = what to search
   Basically the formula should return the number of how many times "what" is in "where"
2. `=TEXTJOIN(";";TRUE;TRANSPOSE(range))`

This is my try for the first formula, which obviously fails:

```
Function formu(unde As Range, ce As String) As Long
formu = Sum(Len(unde) - Len(Substitute(unde, ce, ""))) / Len(ce)
End Function
```

Any suggestions? I think I'm starting to learn that Excel Formulas are not working in the same way here and I have to use VBAs Formulas and calculations, right?

Comment: Side note, but the `SUM` is superfluous here.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to accomplish and what the problem you face is.

Comment: Use [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) here and you're just about there.

Comment: Worth noting that Excel is trying to go in the opposite direction: fewer needs to use VBA for UDFs (eg new dynamic array functions, LAMBDA functionality coming etc). Bear in mind also that creating VBA UDFs can start to trigger security warnings as your file becomes a .xlsm rather than a .xlsx.